# Help conceive of some possible disasters that threaten the solar system and countermeasures

Tags: science-fiction, natural-disasters

I'm trying to envision a science fiction setting:

### Scientific Discovery:

Scientists have captured and analyzed some of the neutrino signal information and found that the information is highly mathematically regular. By analyzing this data, scientists have found that some of this data matches highly with the results deduced from current human physical theories.

It has also been found that such neutrino signals may be transmitting messages across the speed of light, and scientists have analyzed that such neutrinos may have entered miniature wormholes in cosmic space and entered higher dimensions.

Scientists have deduced from this that such regular neutrino messages may be a medium to maintain the current rules of operation of cosmic objects.

People accordingly further deduce that our universe is likely to be the result of program simulation, similar to our human game program, and the medium of message transmission is neutrino signals, which can enter higher dimensions of space to achieve superluminal propagation, change astronomical phenomena and even the past, but of course such changes can not violate the cause and effect relationship.

### Scientific Research:

Scientists have succeeded in deciphering part of the neutrino command structure and attempted to send such signals, determining the direction of sending based on the historical path of naturally captured neutrino signals, and have succeeded in changing and observing part of an astronomical phenomenon dozens of light-years away in a relatively short period of time in this way (this phenomenon does not violate the law of causality, since the astronomical phenomenon was observed at a time later than the sending of the signal).

### Neutrino experiment constraints:

Limited by the computational accuracy of human computers, human determination of the coordinates of the location where the astronomical phenomenon changes has a large precision error, on the order of a few hundred astronomical units.

Limited by the current progress of human physics research, it may be difficult for humans to create astronomical phenomena that are unable to be explained by current physics. For example, humans can create black holes relatively easily because humans are familiar with the physical properties of black holes. But humans may not be able to create dark matter planets because humans are unfamiliar with the physical properties of dark matter.

Due to energy limitations, it is often more difficult to create astronomical phenomena with greater total energy.

### Disaster Setting:

Some scheming research organizations have created a threat that will destroy the sun or solar system within a few decades by sending neutrino signal commands, but the threat has not yet had a significant impact on the solar system.

The fictional setting makes it almost impossible to counter this threat by similar means. A counterexample to one would be if you created a black hole that approached the solar system at a very high speed and annexed the sun within a few decades, however, humans could create similar black holes and use gravity to alter their trajectory thus eliminating the threat.

Currently all the scientists in the world can't do anything about it.
Instead, the novel's ending eliminates the threat by discovering more cutting edge physical theories and sending neutrino commands based on calculations derived from the theories to eliminate the threat.

### My questions are:

1. Are you guys able to conceive of a disaster setting that could destroy the solar system decades from now that could not be countered using similar means, such as the black holes I mentioned above?
2. Are you guys able to conceive of a more physically advanced setup for defusing said catastrophe?
3. Are there any irrationalities in my scientific scenario above? If so, please help point them out.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please read the tag description. hard science and science based are mutually exclusive\

Comment: A couple of suggestions.  1) The wall of text is hard to read, please look at formatting and breaking up into paragraphs.  2) Remove anything that is extraneous or contradictory - for example, the neutrino signals are FTL but somehow don't violate causality - skip the FTL part altogether if it's not relevant. (Or were you thinking of tachyons instead of neutrinos?)  3) It seems like you are asking us not for a setting but for the plot of your story, which is a reason to close the question as off-topic, but as written the question is unclear.

Comment: Hi @TaraKara. We're lenient with new users, but please note the following for future reference. (a) You are allowed to ask one and only one question. Asking multiple questions (no matter how related) is literally a reason to close the post. (b) Brainstorming is discouraged (especially if the problem is writer's block), so how you word your question is important. SE wants you to focus on a single, reasonably objective problem. (c) Be cautious with "realism." Even physicists are willing to suspend their disbelief for a good story. Cheers.

Comment: Since this is a simulated universe that can be affected by in-simulation events, since we don't know the communication protocol that is being exploited, this can't be definitively answered, so it is opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

Some stranger objects for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrophysical_jet s that are visible when they hit gas, but become invisible, when they go through nothing that is susceptible to energy.

So that is quite the setup, extremely dense lances of invisible beam going through space. You do not see them until they hit something - and when they hit something you are likely to miss interpret that "hit" as a local breakdown of the laws of physics. Meanwhile nothing got broken, its just - a "snipe" over impossible distances, impossible times, blasting away at the neighborhoods sun, turning a peaceful red giant into a supernova via reactions it could have never sustained by itself.

Now the simulation is supposed to be realistic, modeled after the external universe- but at the same time, it is supposed to protect interesting results.

Which means, when a beam threatens a outcome, relevant to the exterior - something protective will happen. Which is just a dumb subroutine spawning stuff to catch the beam, but not preventing a solar system crashing into that shield.

Answer (score 0):

I think a possible disaster setting is that a large wormhole appears hundreds of AU from the sun, and the wormhole is approaching the sun at an extremely high speed. However, scientists have found that the wormhole is extremely unstable and strange materials are leaking out, which means that the wormhole may collapse rapidly in a few years, and the collapse will cause a disaster like a supernova explosion (or a black hole). If the wormhole is gravity-free like an Ellis wormhole, then changing its trajectory through gravity may not be effective. As for the solution, I haven't thought of it yet. This is just my guess, I'm not sure if it's scientific enough.

Comment: You have tagged your question as science based, and then self post an answer of which you are not sure if it is scientific enough?

Comment: It's your simulation so you make the rules!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the situation is:

1. The universe is a simulation.
2. Someone has learned how to issue commands to the simulation engine to produce astrophysical events.
3. They've been fool enough to publish this discovery, and someone else wants to use it to end the world.
4. You want an astrophysical event that can be created by the simulation engine, but can't be countered or negated by the simulation engine, to serve as the driver of your plot.

Is that correct? If so, the question is ill-founded, because *you* control the abilities of the simulation engine, so it can do whatever you allow. You're heading for the worst kind of "Hollywood crisis plot" which doesn't make sense on its own terms. However, there's a way out of this.

### Your problem is software security, not astrophysics

It's quite bizarre that the simulation engine allows commands to be issued from inside it, but the motives of creators of simulated universes are unknown anyway (and thus unlikely to make interesting stories). Possible responses to hacking from inside the simulation include:

- "Congratulations, your species has passed the test. Now you get to join the advanced civilisations."
- "Panic! Shut down simulator."
- No imediate response. The hacking is allowed carry on, until it does the equivalent of `sudo shutdown` and the stars all start blinking in unison to indicate that the system is going down.

The last of those is somewhat close to your desired plot, and the way out of it could be "more advanced physical means" to indicate that "Yes, you have the right to control the simulator, you just hit the wrong key." However, you need to provide a way, preferably not a literal [deus ex machina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deus_ex_machina), for that more advanced knowledge to become available.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have added some restrictions to the original question. Humans cannot create arbitrary celestial phenomena.